# Facebook share shows wrong image

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

my question is about a weird cache issue with facebook open graph. My server provides an html document with the properly meta tags for facebook share utility.

Provided meta tags are: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:image, og:description, og:site_name, og:updated_time.

Now the facebook url debugger brings the correct data, all fields have the correct data, but when i lanch the popup, with the url containing the html mentioned above, the image is wrong, it shows me an old image or the site logo... i thinks it is a cache trouble, and i don´t know how to solve.

I have tried some solutions but are bad solutions, like adding a timestamp at the end of querystring. This is bad because it reset the shared count.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you change the image but not the URL of that image?

Comment: the image changes because users can share multiple articles from my site, so, the image url change properly

Comment: I mean, did you update the image itself, but leave the value of the og:image tag on the URL unchanged? If so, facebook caches the old image

Comment: the og:image tag value changes with the image itself, because a new html (with a new image and a new meta tag) is loaded, but the image presented is an old cached image

Comment: without seeing the URL you're sharing, the image you think should be used and the image which is actually being used, it's hard to be sure, but the problem is almost certainly that the URL you're sharing has the wrong image tag, or the image URL you're providing is a) wrong, b) broken or c) was cached by Facebook when that image URL pointed to a different file